# Ruby on Rails: difference between text_area and text_area_tag helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in Ruby on Rails: What is the difference between `text_area` and `text_area_tag` helpers?

More importantly, I would like to know **which one is more suited** to long HTML text input (specifically in my case, **blog posts**) ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is that if you use `form_for`, pass `ActiveRecord` object to it and pass, let's say, `f` to block, it is much more convenient to use for example

```
<%= f.text_area :body %>
```

because it sets proper id, name and value automatically.
There's no difference between these helpers in handling long HTML text inputs, but if you want to use it for `ActiveRecord` object form, you should use `text_area` because, as I said, it's more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of form helpers: those that specifically [work with model attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) and [those that don‘t](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html).

Ref [`text_area`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#M002277) which specifically work with model

```
text_area(:post, :body, :cols => 20, :rows => 40)
```

this will create following html

```
   <textarea cols="20" rows="40" id="post_body" name="post[body]">
     #{@post.body}
   </textarea>
```

Ref [`text_area_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M002245) which doesn‘t rely on an Active Record objec

```
text_area_tag 'post'
```

will create following

```
<textarea id="post" name="post"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

text_area set tailored for accessing a specified attribute (identified by method) on an object assigned to the template (identified by object)
text_area(:post, :body, :cols => 20, :rows => 40) generate:

```
<textarea cols="20" rows="40" id="post_body" name="post[body]">
  #{@post.body}
</textarea>
```

And text_area_tag 'post' generate

```
<textarea id="post" name="post"></textarea>
```

For more information, look:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_area_tag
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_area

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.text_area :attribute_name %>

<%= text_area_tag :any_name, :any_value %>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use `form_for` (always recommended) to render form then use

`<%= f.text_area ....`

otherwise you have to use

`<%= text_area_tag ....`

either will serve the same and no impact on input data (text) size